# Excel workbook stays open after my program was force-closed

Tags: python, excel, memory, xlwings

I'm writing code using xlwings library that takes all sheets in an Excel file that start with the letters "CC" and split them into different Excel files.

Here is the function:

```
def create(directory):
    directory = r"{}".format(directory)

    excelApp = xw.App(visible = False)
    wb = excelApp.books.open(excelFile)

    for sheet in wb.sheets:
        name = sheet.name
        if name[:2] == "CC":
            # remove all spaces in string then set is to be CC + whatever is after first two chars 
            name = name.replace(" ", "")
            name = f"CC {name[2:]}"

            # copying the sheet
            try:
                sheet.api.Copy()
                wb_new = xw.books.active
                wb_new.save(f'{directory}\\{name}.xlsx')
                wb_new.close()
            except Exception as error:
                print(f"Error creating sheet {name}, error: {error}")
```

When the function runs, a temporary Excel file is created with a name similar to my main sheet except it starts with "~$" and this file gets deleted when the function is finished. The problem is if the code stops while the function is running (eg CTRL C) then this temporary file stays and eats memory, I have to go into the resource monitor and terminate it. How can I fix this?

Comment: Temporary files don't "eat memory".  You're starting an instance of the Excel application, and that application will still be running (not using memory).  You can catch the Ctrl-C by using `except KeyboardInterrupt` in the code that calls this, and cleaning up the instance yourself.

Comment: I thought it was eating memory because while playing around trying to figure out what is wrong, I had 3 or 4 instances open and my computer started lagging and not even restarting it fixed the problem until I hopped into resource monitor. 

Are there alternatives to catch the ctrl c? This function is in a tkinter GUI that is called by button click so if the user just exits the program while the loop is running then I keyboard interrupt won't catch it.

Comment: If this is a button click handler, then the UI will not respond to another button click until this function returns.

Comment: I'm using a thread to run it so the UI is still responsive even while the function is running

Comment: Why does the code stop? Wouldn't that be the thing you should be chasing?

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way is using [with xw.App](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.App) (available since Version 0.24.3) to ensure that everything is properly cleaned up again and to prevent zombie processes after an error (works even if you use a hidden instance).

```
import xlwings as xw

path = r"test.xlsx"

with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xw.Book(path)

    # Do your thing here, e.g.:
    wb.sheets[0]["A1"].value = 1000

    # At the end save and close the workbook or in your case rather workbooks.
    wb.save(path)
    wb.close()
```